# hw() function in R doesn't work properly on my laptop only

Tags: r, forecasting, holtwinters

I'm studying time series and need to use hw() function. I cannot make it working even on a simple code based on the co2 dataset :

```
library(forecast)
co2_train=window(co2,start=c(1959,1),end=c(1989,12))
co2_test=window(co2,start=c(1990,1),end=c(1997,12))
h=hw(co2_train,seasonal='additive',damped=FALSE,h=96) #code stops to be executed here
accuracy(h)
```

When I load the R Markdown, the first time I try to run it I get the following error :

> Error in ets(x, "AAA", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, gamma = gamma, phi = phi, :
> No model able to be fitted

Then if I re-run the code, RStudio is compiling indefinitively and I need to restart it to work again. All other models are working (ARIMA, Neural networks forecast...). Only this function makes trouble.

I tried to create a new file, a new project, restart R Studio, reinstall R Studio... with no luck.

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code ran on my machine without a problem. I can only speculate that there may be an issue with the library installation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to uninstall forecast library (remove.package("forecast")), restarted RStudio, and reinstalled it, but the issue is the same...

Comment: Also tried to uninstall RStudio, reboot my laptop and reinstall it. But the issue remains...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the reason, but a brand new installation on a new laptop at work helped me to get rid of this issue. Maybe some options which remained in my other laptop after uninstallation.